# Inconsistent treatment of Ranges and Values in function arguments

Tags: excel

Set up the following:

```
A1: FALSE
A2: 1
A3: =MIN(A1,A2)
A4: =MIN(FALSE,1)
```

A3 returns 1, as expected (the MIN function is supposed to ignore logical values, hence MINA exists). A4 returns 0.

Any ideas what is going on? Were functions overloaded I would suppose it is implicitly converting the FALSE to 0 before being passed in to the function.

This is under Excel version 14.0.6023, 32-bit, if it matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Office article on the MIN function [(found here)](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MIN-function-61635d12-920f-4ce2-a70f-96f202dcc152):

> - Logical values and text representations of numbers that you type directly into the list of arguments are counted.
> - If an argument is an array or reference, only numbers in that array or reference are used. Empty cells, logical values, or text in the
>     array or reference are ignored.

So when you supply `FALSE` directly into the function, it *is* counted and therefore becomes the minimum value.

Comment: thanks. This is damn annoying is it makes it impossible to directly use an construct like `=MIN(IF(A4>0,A4,FALSE),IF(A5>0,A5,FALSE))` etc. The only workaround I could think of was to use a FALSE in a cell, and link to that in the False part of the IF, or something inelegant like using 10^99 as the False part.